# multiple awaits and async methods in an application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous, async-await

I'm in the process of converting our data layer for a fairly large and complex WCF application to talk to the database asynchronously.

This has resulted in `async` and `await`s being littered everywhere in the calling/consuming code.

Looking at the stack trace for a typical request I can already see many sections for the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter` doing it's thing with `await`. And I have only just started this task!

I understand what .net does when it encounters `async`/`await`, so my question is the following: Is the extra overhead associated working with `async`/`await` worth it when the result is quite a few async methods from the beginning of a request to the end? I understand the benefits of calling the database asynchronously but is there a limit? Particularly when the calling application is fairly large and complex (or more appropriately a large and long call-stack).

Thanks.

Comment: If you're worried about the performance of your code, there is only one way to be sure: measure it yourself.

Comment: I understand. And that is what I intend to do. However I am asking for the experiences of other developers in this regard.